# strcat() int variable + C

Tags: c, int, strcat

I need to print something on this form:

> ```
> [1] "text"
> [2] "text"
> [3] "text"
> ```

I'm using `strcat()`, so I want to concatenate "text" to a buffer.
I get "text" one element at a time in a buffer, and I need to concatenate it to a string.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to get the [number] part in the front.

First, is it possible to `strcat()` an `int`?
I have tried, but can't seem to get it to work.

Second, is it possible to get the `'[' ']'` around the variable? (I need the `int` value to increase for each loop).
This may be a stupid question, but I really can't figure out how to solve this, and I need the menu to be on this form or something similar.

Comment: Have you tried `sprintf`?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, try `sprintf` to put your integer into a buffer string. Then, concatenate this string with the one you wanted.

Something like this:

```
char string[STRING_SIZE] = "text "
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
sprintf(buffer, "%d", number);
strcat(string, buffer)
```

Adjust the sizes for your situation.

Comment: 1) `string` overflow, 2) `buffer` overflow with large numbers.  -1

Comment: Should use `snprintf` for safety.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter to know the number for each string of text :

```
char    buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int     counter = 1;

while (/* condition for continuing reading buffer */) {
    buffer = //readBuffer();
    printf("[%d] %s ", counter, buffer);
    counter++;
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

> First, is it possible to strcat() an int?

No, you have to convert the int in char *. Look at the following implementation : http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/groff/groff-10/groff/libgroff/itoa.c.

> Second, is it possible to get the '[' ']' around the variable?

Just use strcat to add this

```
strcat( buffer, text1 );
strcat( buffer, "[" )
// ...
```

Comment: You mean to a string when you talk of `char*`?

Comment: Yes it is what i mean.